# Autocomplete not filling out entire form

Tags: html, forms, autocomplete

The form on our checkout page has a very clunky autocomplete experience and only a couple fields actually fill in with the data at a time.

Website - https://allvolleyball.com

I've gone into my browser settings and made sure to fill out my autocomplete profile entirely which didn't make a difference. I looked in our template files for this page and the input fields all have the correct autocomplete attributes set on them as well. See form code below.

```
  <fieldset><legend>Billing Information</legend>

    <div>
      <label for="first_name"><span class="req">*</span> First Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" size="30" maxlength="50" value="" autocomplete="billing fname">
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="last_name"><span class="req">*</span> Last Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="" autocomplete="billing lname">
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="company">Organization:</label>
      <input type="text" name="company" id="company" value="">
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="billing_address1"><span class="req">*</span> Billing Address:</label>
      <input type="text" name="billing_address1" id="billing_address1" value="" autocomplete="billing address-line1">
    </div>

    <div>  <input type="text" name="billing_address2" value="" autocomplete="billing address-line2">
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="billing_city"><span class="req">*</span> City:</label>
      <input type="text" name="billing_city" id="billing_city" value="" autocomplete="billing locality">
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="billing_country"><span class="req">*</span> Country:</label>
      <select name="billing_country" id="billing_country">
       <option label="United States" value="United States">United States</option>
       <option label="Canada" value="Canada">Canada</option>

     </select>
   </div>

   <div>
    <span class="label"><span class="req">*</span> State/Province:</span>
    <select name="billing_state" id="billing_state">
     <option label="Alabama" value="AL">Alabama</option>
   </select>

   <select id="ca_billing_province" name="" style="display: none;">
    <option label="Alberta" value="AB">Alberta</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" id="billing_province" value="" name="" style="display: none;">
</div>

<div>
  <label for="billing_zip"><span class="req">*</span> Postal Code:</label>
  <input type="text" name="billing_zip" id="billing_zip" value="" size="15" maxlength="30" autocomplete="billing postal-code">
</div>

<div>
  <label for="phone"><span class="req">*</span> Phone Number:</label>
  <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="(xxx) xxx-xxxx" value="" autocomplete="billing tel">
</div>

<div>
  <label for="billing_email"><span class="req">*</span> Email Address:</label>
  <input type="text" id="billing_email" name="email" value="" autocomplete="billing email">
</div>

</fieldset>

</div>
```

Here's what I'm currently getting when I use autocomplete -

[image: broken autocomplete]

I would expect pretty much all of these fields to fill in with my data.